# CSS animations - fading in and fading out

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to do some animations on a menu in CSS. Below is the code I have to get the menu to fade in when I hover over the heading. I've also added similar CSS rules for fading out but I can't get it to work the way I want.

Tried a few things but the best I could do was getting it to fade in and then as soon as it is at full opacity it fades out again till the end of the animation and then just displays the block, so it basically fades ina and then out before just appearing as if there was no animation.

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
ul >li >ul{
  display:none;
}
ul >li:hover >ul{
  display:block;
}

.fade_in {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade_in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fade_in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade_in {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade_in {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.fade_out {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade_in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fade_in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade_out {
  from {opacity: 1} 
  to {opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade_out {
  from {opacity: 1} 
  to {opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Heading
    <ul class="fade_in">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, what do you want it to do?

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks for your comment sorry if I didn't explain it well enough, I want it to fade back out when you're no longer hovering over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is by far easier using a CSS **transition** instead of an *animation*, like so:

```
transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
```

Because you can neither animate nor transition the `display` property, I've changed the default state from `display: none;` to `opacity: 0;`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul>li>ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

ul>li:hover>ul {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Heading
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this but don't think it will work for me as I think I need it to be display:none when it is not visible rather than just the opacity as this element will be covering other items on screen

Comment: You can solve that via CSS as well. `ul>li>ul { pointer-events: none }` and `ul>li:hover>ul { pointer-events: all; }`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

HTML

```
<div>Heading
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div>ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover>ul {
    pointer-events: all;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```